# SQL Server R service - query results as character instead of factor

Tags: sql-server, r, sql-server-2016

I am using SQL Server R Service and I am filling my @input_data_1 with a query. The resulting dataframe is factor by default when the column is varchar. How to obtain results as character data type?

**STORED PROCEDURE**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myProc
AS
EXEC sp_execute_external_script
@language = N'R'
,@script=N'
df <- InputDataSet
x <- str(df)
OutputDataSet <- as.data.frame(x)
'
@input_data_1 = N'SELECT * FROM MyTable'
--will result in factor data type for both col1 and col2.
```

**MyTable**

```
col1 (varchar) | col2 (varchar)
-------------------------------
     text1     |   text4
     text2     |   text5
     text3     |   text6
```

Comment: you could just convert it using as.character, would that be an acceptable answer?

Comment: I could but I don't want to do it one-by-one. Currently I have about 15 columns, what if I have 50 columns next?

Comment: I encountered this as well, and it's really irritating.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a reproduceable answer.

If you may have many columns, and don't want to change them individually, you need to use an apply function.

In the example below I make a table df1 (with strings as characters), convert the characters to factors (df2), then convert them back (this is the part in which you will be interested) in df3.

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 <- tribble(~col1, ~col2,
               "text1", "text2",
               "text3", "text6",
               "text1", "text2"
)

df2 <- as.data.frame(sapply(X = df1, FUN = as.factor))

df3 <- as.data.frame(sapply(X = df2, FUN = as.character), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```